# Custom renderer for Radio Group / SelectOne does nothing

Tags: jsf, xpages, jsf-1.2

The XPages renderer for a radio group put everything into tables and is basically terrible. I'm trying to fix this with a custom renderer. I've tried a lot of things but right now I'm stuck because I simply have no information to go further.

My renderer is declared in faces-config like so:

```
<renderer>
   <component-family>javax.faces.SelectOne</component-family>
   <renderer-type>itd.alcs.controller.Radio</renderer-type>
   <renderer-class>itd.alcs.controller.RadioGroupRenderer</renderer-class>
</renderer>
<renderer>
   <component-family>javax.faces.Input</component-family>
   <renderer-type>itd.alcs.controller.Radio</renderer-type>
   <renderer-class>itd.alcs.controller.RadioGroupRenderer</renderer-class>
</renderer>
```

My renderer code is:

```
public class RadioGroupRenderer extends com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.RadioRenderer {

    public RadioGroupRenderer() {
        System.out.println("RadioGroupRenderer");
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("encodeBegin");
        super.encodeBegin(context, component);
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("encodeEnd");
        Writer writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        XspSelectOneRadio tcomponent = component instanceof XspSelectOneRadio ? (XspSelectOneRadio) component : null;
        if (tcomponent == null) {
            System.out.println("Nothing");
            writer.write("Nothing");
        }

        if (tcomponent.isReadonly()) {
            // writer.write(tcomponent.getValue().toString());
            System.out.println("Read Only");
            writer.write("Read Only");
        } else {
            //super.encodeEnd(context, component);
            System.out.println("Edit");
            writer.write("Edit");
        }
    }
}
```

Something is happening when I apply this renderer-type. And that something is that I get no output. Nothing in my response. No errors in the console. None of the console messages I put in in the constructor or encodeBegin or encodeEnd.

If I change the name of the renderer-type or renderer-class to something invalid... still nothing. No errors, no output. I don't know if something is trapping my error and handling them silently or.... what?

How can I figure out what I'm doing wrong here? Bonus points if you can TELL me what I'm doing wrong, but what I really want to know is how to get some sort of feedback to troubleshoot this myself.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question in case anyone else runs into this....

The `<renderer>...</renderer>` tags need to go inside `<render-kit></render-kit>` tags. You'd think I'd have come across that in 4 hours of searching, but no.

Comment: Put something up on OpenNTF if you get it going! I hate the tables that XPages does for radio groups. thanks, Howard